# Get inner part of Array PHP

Tags: php

How do I get inner part of a long array in PHP :
Example:

print_r($array) gives:

```
Razorpay\Api\Collection Object
(
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [entity] => collection
            [count] => 1
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Razorpay\Api\Payment Object
                        (
                            [attributes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => payid
                                    [entity] => payment
                                    [amount] => 1000
                                    [currency] => INR
                                    [status] => captured
                                    [order_id] => orderid
                                    [invoice_id] => 
                                    [international] => 
                                    [method] => card
                                    [amount_refunded] => 0
                                    [refund_status] => 
                                    [captured] => 1
                                    [description] => D.
                                    [card_id] => id
                                    [bank] => 
                                    [wallet] => 
                                    [vpa] => 
                                    [email] => example@example.com
                                    [contact] => +91
                                    [notes] => Razorpay\Api\Payment Object
                                        (
                                            [attributes:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [address] => add
                                                    [merchant_order_id] => orid
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [fee] => 20
                                    [tax] => 0
                                    [error_code] => 
                                    [error_description] => 
                                    [created_at] => 1580641472
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is Razorpay Payment details returned.
How do I get id and other innermost items from this array
I want to get id and status and check if status is captured or failed to verify the payment, but, I can't get it anyway. Please help

Comment: are you using yii?

Comment: `$array->items[0]->id` like that. But i am too sure that you can access protected attributes directly.

Comment: Why do you access like so? As it says it is a collection, so you can easily iterate over each and every item.

Comment: As it says - it seems protected. Did you try to iterate over it or tried to call function called `toArray()` which is specified in `Razorpay\Api\Entity.php` which is parent of `Razorpay\Api\Payment.php` as you can see in their [source files](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-php/tree/master/src)

Comment: toArray() gives Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got:

```
$payment = $api->order->fetch($_POST["razorpayorderid"])->payments();
$payid = $payment["items"][0]["id"];
```